# Deleting characters in the list created using the getlist method

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I created a list using the `getlist` method in my django project, and then I use this list in my form. Every time I update the form, it automatically adds a new character to the list. How can I prevent this? I used the strip and split methods but no results. I am attaching my codes below.

models.py

```
class Records(models.Model):    
    medications = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True,blank=True)
    scale_used = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True,blank=True)
    way_of_application = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=True,blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def insertList(request):
     records = Records()
     records.medications = request.POST.getlist('medications')
     records.scale_used = request.POST.getlist('scale_used')
     records.way_of_application = request.POST.getlist('way_of_application')
        
     records.save()
     return redirect('/index/tables')

def getList(request,id):
    edit_records = Records.objects.get(id=id)
    if edit_records.medications is not None:
        edit_records.medications = edit_records.medications.strip('"]["').split(',')
    if edit_records.scale_used is not None:
        edit_records.scale_used = edit_records.scale_used.strip('"]["').split(',')
    if  edit_records.way_of_application is not None:
        edit_records.way_of_application = edit_records.way_of_application.strip('"]["').split(',')

   return render(request,"update_record.html",{"Records": edit_records})
```

**Output:**

```
medications = ['\'\\\'PULCET 40MG FLAKON\\\'"\'', '\'"\\\'METPAMİD 10MG/2ML AMPUL\\\'"\'', '\'"\\\'İZOTONİK 250ML\\\'"\'']
scale_used = ['\'\\\'1 FLAKON\\\'"\'', ' \' " \\\'1 AMP\\\'"\'', ' " \' 1 ADET\'"', ' \' " \\\'\\\'\'']
way_of_application = ['\'\\\'I.V İnfüzyon\\\'"\'', '\'"\\\'I.V\\\'"\'', '\'"\\\'I.V\\\'"\'', '\'"\\\'\\\'\'']
```

I have given the codes I used with the outputs above, can you help with this?

Comment: Why on earth are all these extra chars in your data in the first place???

Comment: Please share the code that makes the request, it does *not* make any sense how the data is transferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add only the data without tuple for that you can join and save the data

```
def insertList(request):
     records = Records()
     records.medications = ','.join(request.POST.getlist('medications'))
     records.scale_used = ','.join(request.POST.getlist('scale_used'))
     records.way_of_application = ','.join(request.POST.getlist('way_of_application'))
        
     records.save()
     return redirect('/index/tables')
```